# Finding a General Pattern for the Partial fraction of $\frac{1}{{{\left( 1+x \right)}^{n}}\left( 1+{{x}^{2}} \right)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

I am interested in finding the general pattern for the partial fraction of:
$$
\frac{1}{{{\left( 1+x \right)}^{n}}\left( 1+{{x}^{2}} \right)}
$$ 
where $n=1,2,3,......$
here is the partial fractions from $n=1\quad to\quad 10$
$$
\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & \frac{1-u}{2\left( {{u}^{2}}+1 \right)}+\frac{1}{2(u+1)}  \\
   2 & -\frac{u}{2\left( {{u}^{2}}+1 \right)}+\frac{1}{2(u+1)}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{2}}}  \\
   3 & \frac{-u-1}{4\left( {{u}^{2}}+1 \right)}+\frac{1}{4(u+1)}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{2}}}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{3}}}  \\
   4 & \frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{3}}}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{4}}}-\frac{1}{4\left( {{u}^{2}}+1 \right)}+\frac{1}{4{{(u+1)}^{2}}}  \\
   5 & \frac{u-1}{8\left( {{u}^{2}}+1 \right)}-\frac{1}{8(u+1)}+\frac{1}{4{{(u+1)}^{3}}}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{4}}}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{5}}}  \\
   6 & \frac{u}{8\left( {{u}^{2}}+1 \right)}-\frac{1}{8(u+1)}-\frac{1}{8{{(u+1)}^{2}}}+\frac{1}{4{{(u+1)}^{4}}}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{5}}}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{6}}}  \\
   7 & \frac{u+1}{16\left( {{u}^{2}}+1 \right)}-\frac{1}{16(u+1)}-\frac{1}{8{{(u+1)}^{2}}}-\frac{1}{8{{(u+1)}^{3}}}+\frac{1}{4{{(u+1)}^{5}}}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{6}}}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{7}}}  \\
   8 & -\frac{1}{8{{(u+1)}^{3}}}-\frac{1}{8{{(u+1)}^{4}}}+\frac{1}{4{{(u+1)}^{6}}}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{7}}}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{8}}}+\frac{1}{16\left( {{u}^{2}}+1 \right)}-\frac{1}{16{{(u+1)}^{2}}}  \\
   9 & \frac{1-u}{32\left( {{u}^{2}}+1 \right)}+\frac{1}{32(u+1)}-\frac{1}{16{{(u+1)}^{3}}}-\frac{1}{8{{(u+1)}^{4}}}-\frac{1}{8{{(u+1)}^{5}}}+\frac{1}{4{{(u+1)}^{7}}}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{8}}}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{9}}}  \\
   10 & -\frac{u}{32\left( {{u}^{2}}+1 \right)}+\frac{1}{32(u+1)}+\frac{1}{32{{(u+1)}^{2}}}-\frac{1}{16{{(u+1)}^{4}}}-\frac{1}{8{{(u+1)}^{5}}}-\frac{1}{8{{(u+1)}^{6}}}+\frac{1}{4{{(u+1)}^{8}}}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{9}}}+\frac{1}{2{{(u+1)}^{10}}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$$
Can any body see the pattern if any, Can we write it as a sum??

**Problem background:**
I am trying to find a closed form for the integral:
$$\int{\frac{1}{{{\left( 1+x \right)}^{n}}\left( 1+{{x}^{2}} \right)}dx}$$

Comment: Perhaps I'm quite late, but I just saw this.  With the substitution $x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$ you will get:
$$\int{\frac{1}{{{\left( 1+x \right)}^{n}}\left( 1+{{x}^{2}} \right)}dx}=-\frac{1}{2^n} \int \frac{(1+t)^n}{1+t^2}dt$$
Now use binomial expansion :) But before I would suggest to write $t^2+1=(t+i)(t-i)$.

Comment: it is never too late...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Lemma.** For $|x+1| < \sqrt{2}$, we have
>   $$ \begin{gathered}
> \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \cos(k\pi/4)\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^k = \frac{1-x}{1+x^2}, \\
> \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sin(k\pi/4)\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^k = \frac{1+x}{1+x^2}. 
> \end{gathered}$$

In particular, using $\cos(x) + \sin(x) = \sqrt{2}\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})$, we obtain

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin((k+1)\pi/4)}{2^{(k+1)/2}} (x+1)^k = \frac{1}{1+x^2} $$

for $|x+1| < \sqrt{2}$. Plugging this to OP's rational function,

$$ \frac{1}{(1+x)^n(1+x^2)}
= \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin(k\pi/4)}{2^{k/2}} \frac{1}{(x+1)^{n+1-k}} \right) + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin((n+k+1)\pi/4)}{2^{(n+k+1)/2}} (x+1)^k. $$

The latter sum can be further simplified by using the addition formula for $\sin$, yielding

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin((n+k+1)\pi/4)}{2^{(n+k+1)/2}} (x+1)^k
&= \frac{\sin((n+1)\pi/4)}{2^{(n+1)/2}} \frac{1-x}{1+x^2} + \frac{\cos((n+1)\pi/4)}{2^{(n+1)/2}} \frac{1+x}{1+x^2} \\
&= \frac{\cos(n\pi/4)}{2^{n/2}} \frac{1}{1+x^2} - \frac{\sin(n\pi/4)}{2^{n/2}} \frac{x}{1+x^2}
\end{align*}

Combining altogether, we get

> $$ \frac{1}{(1+x)^n(1+x^2)}
> = \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin(k\pi/4)}{2^{k/2}} \frac{1}{(x+1)^{n+1-k}} \right) + \frac{\cos(n\pi/4)-x \sin(n\pi/4)}{2^{n/2}(1+x^2)}. $$

Although this is shown initially on the region $|x+1| < \sqrt{2}$, this continues to hold everywhere since any two rational functions which coincide at infinitely many points must be equal.

Comment: Ok this is perfect!!!!! where you found this lemma???

Comment: @logo it is the general series expansion centred around the point x = -1, which can be done using complex partial fractions, or, if you want to have additional difficulties, you can inductively establish the general term and remain inside the real field.

Comment: Now its clear..thank you

Answer (score 6):

Put
\begin{equation*}
 f(x)=\dfrac{1}{(1+x)^n(1+x^2)}.
\end{equation*}
Then the partial fraction of $f(x)$ has the form
\begin{equation*}
 f(x) =\dfrac{ax+b}{1+x^2} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{c_k}{(1+x)^{n+1-k}}\tag {1}
\end{equation*}
or
\begin{equation*}
 f(x) = \dfrac{d_1}{x+i}+\dfrac{d_2}{x-i}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{c_k}{(1+x)^{n+1-k}}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{gather*}
d_1= \underset{x=-i}{\rm{res}}f(x) = \dfrac{1}{(1-i)^n(-2i)}=-\dfrac{e^{i\frac{n\pi}{4}}}{\sqrt{2}^{n}2i}\\[2ex]
d_2= \underset{x=i}{\rm{res}}f(x) = \dfrac{1}{(1+i)^n(2i)}=\dfrac{e^{-i\frac{n\pi}{4}}}{\sqrt{2}^{n}2i}.
\end{gather*}
However,
\begin{gather*}
a=d_1+d_2 =-\dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{4}\right)}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}\\[2ex]
b=i(d_2-d_1)= \dfrac{\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{4}\right)}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}.
\end{gather*}
Furthermore
\begin{gather*}
 c_k = \underset{x=-1}{\rm{res}}(1+x)^{n-k}f(x)=
 \underset{x=-1}{\rm{res}}\dfrac{1}{(1+x)^k(1+x^2)}=\\[2ex]
 \left.\dfrac{1}{(k-1)!}\dfrac{d^{k-1}}{dx^{k-1}}\left(\dfrac{1}{2i}\left(\dfrac{1}{x-i}-\dfrac{1}{x+i}\right)\right)\right|_{x=-1} =\\[2ex] \dfrac{1}{2i(k-1)!}(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!\left(\dfrac{1}{(-1-i)^{k}}-\dfrac{1}{(-1+i)^{k}}\right)=
 \dfrac{1}{2i}\left(\dfrac{1}{(1-i)^{k}}-\dfrac{1}{(1+i)^{k}}\right)=\\[2ex]
 \dfrac{1}{2i}\left(\dfrac{e^{i\frac{k\pi}{4}}}{\sqrt{2}^{k}}-\dfrac{e^{-i\frac{k\pi}{4}}}{\sqrt{2}^{k}}\right) = \dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{4}\right)}{2^{\frac{k}{2}}}
 \end{gather*}
 Now we know all coefficients in (1).

Comment: the power of residues ....thanks and +1

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to carry this
almost all the way through
and stop just before the final step
because I got tired of
all the necessary details.

$\begin{array}\\
f_n(x)
&=\frac{1}{{{\left( 1+x \right)}^{n}}\left( 1+{{x}^{2}} \right)}\\
&=\frac{a+bx}{1+x^2}+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{c_k}{(1+x)^k}\\
g_n(x)
&=f_n(x)(1+x^2)(1+x)^n\\
&=1\\
&=(a+bx)(1+x)^n+\sum_{k=1}^n c_k(1+x^2)(1+x)^{n-k}\\
g_n(-1)
&=2c_n\\
c_n
&=\frac12\\
g_n(i)
&=1\\
&=(a+bi)(1+i)^n\\
&=2^{n/2}(a+bi)(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}})^n\\
&=2^{n/2}(a+bi)(e^{i\pi/4})^n\\
&=2^{n/2}(a+bi)e^{ni\pi/4}\\
a+bi
&=2^{-n/2}e^{-ni\pi/4}\\
&=2^{-n/2}(\cos(-n\pi/4)+i\sin(-n\pi/4))\\
&=2^{-n/2}(1, \frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}, -i, -\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}, -1, -\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}, i, \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}})
\quad\text{for }n\equiv (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)\bmod 8 \\
&=(\frac1{2^{n/2}}, \frac{1-i}{2^{(n+1)/2}}, -\frac{i}{2^{n/2}}, -\frac{1+i}{2^{(n+1)/2}}, -\frac1{2^{n/2}}, -\frac{1-i}{2^{(n+1)/2}}, \frac{i}{2^{n/2}}, \frac{1+i}{2^{(n+1)/2}})\\
&=(\frac1{2^{4m}}, \frac{1-i}{2^{4m+1}}, -\frac{i}{2^{4m+1}}, -\frac{1+i}{2^{4m+2}}, -\frac1{2^{4m+2}}, -\frac{1-i}{2^{4m+3}}, \frac{i}{2^{4m+3}}, \frac{1+i}{2^{4m+4}})
\quad n=8m+k, k=0...7\\
&=(\frac1{2^{4m}}, \frac{1-i}{2^{4m+1}}, \frac{-i}{2^{4m+1}}, \frac{-1-i}{2^{4m+2}}, \frac{-1}{2^{4m+2}}, \frac{-1+i}{2^{4m+3}}, \frac{i}{2^{4m+3}}, \frac{1+i}{2^{4m+4}})\\
&=\dfrac1{2^{\lceil n/2 \rceil}}(1, 1-i, -i, -1-i, -1, -1+i, i, 1+i)\\
g_n^{(j)}(x)
&=0
\qquad\text{for } j \ge 1\\
&=((a+bx)(1+x)^n)^{(j)}+\sum_{k=1}^n c_k((1+x^2)(1+x)^{n-k})^{(j)}\\
&=u^{(j)}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^n c_kv_k^{(j)}(x)\\
u^{(j)}(x)
&=((a+bx)(1+x)^n)^{(j)}\\
&=\sum_{h=0}^j \binom{j}{h}(a+bx)^{(h)}(1+x)^n)^{(j-h)}\\
(a+bx)^{(h)}
&=a+bx, b, 0, ...
\qquad\text{for }h = 0, 1, 2, ...\\
((1+x)^n)^{(h)}
&=\frac{n!}{(n-h)!}(1+x)^{n-h}\\
v_k^{(j)}(x)
&=((1+x^2)(1+x)^{n-k})^{(j)}(x)\\
&=\sum_{h=0}^j \binom{j}{h}(1+x^2)^{(h)}((1+x)^{n-k})^{(j-h)}(x)\\
(1+x^2)^{(h)}
&=1+x^2, 2x, 2, 0, ...
\qquad \text{for } h=0, 1, 2, ...\\
((1+x)^{n-k})^{(h)}(x)
&=\frac{(n-k)!}{(n-k-h)!}(1+x)^{n-k-h}\\
\end{array}
$

And at this point,
I'll stop.